# How to gracefully exit from absence of expected stdin?

Tags: c, unix, file-io, command-line, std

Normal case, text is cat into the program from stdout of another program.

`cat outExe | myExe`

The program sets `stdin` to a `FILE*` pointer and correctly manipulates the data.

If the program executes without any `stdin` (i.e., `myExe <Enter>`), it produces a segmentation fault.

In the debugger, even thought there was no stdin, the FILE* still has a address, so check for NULL didn't work.

How can I catch this case (program runs with no stdin input) and gracefully exit?

**Current code:**

```
FILE * filePointer = NULL;
filePointer = stdin;
char inputText[300];

if (fgets(inputText, sizeof(inputText), filePointer) != NULL ) //!= EOF
{
   <work with input using strchr, strncpy, >
   <looking for expected format of input>
}
```

In the debugger (not sure if that is the same test) with no input, it hangs at fgets...

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

Comment: As this is tagged `C`, recommend posting some `C` code.

Comment: @oli-charlesworth: does this help if the input is cat from another?

Comment: @chux: good point, added, thanks

Comment: There is always a `stdin`. However, sometimes it immediately returns EOF, so you have to check for that when you first call `fgets`. Or at least initialize your input buffer so that the first byte is a 0 (`NUL`); otherwise, when you try to apply some standard string library function to it, you'll run off the end and into a segfault.

Comment: Where exactly does this program crashes? Without any redirection it should read the input from the keyboard.

Comment: @rici: I updated the code to initially set the filePointer to NULL. I see it is null in the debugger, but as soon as it gets set to stdin, it does get a value...

Comment: @P.S.: Yes, clearly. I didn't contradict that :) What I said was that `fgets` will *return `NULL`* when it hits EOF, and you should test for that. And that you should initialize your buffer (inputText).

Comment: @rici: oooooh!, yes, I actually do, I left the part out here....

Comment: [This is working fine for me](https://gist.github.com/banthar/f4b99c7963ceba439567). It looks like the problem is somewhere else. Can you post enough code to reproduce this?

Comment: @banthar: it is just strchr and strncpy of expected input. I guess it gets to a function like strncpy and then falls off?

Comment: @rici Note; "initialize your input buffer" works in general, but is not safe as an IO error leaves the buffer in an undefined state.  Best to use the `fgets()` result.

Comment: Confident the issue is in `<work with input using strchr, strncpy, > <looking for expected format of input>` or after the `if()` condition.  Need to post more code.

Comment: @chux: certainly. I recommended doing both.

Comment: @chux: It's for work so I am unable to, I know that is on me...any ideas on why it hangs in the debugger at the fgets, is it just waiting for stdin, can I debug stdin at this point?

Comment: 1) "In the debugger (not sure if that is the same test) with no input, it hangs at fgets."  Is this not the expected behavior, waiting for you input from `stdin` (keyboard)?  2) I am concerned that "executes without any stdin ..., it produces a segmentation fault." implies something _after_ the `if (fgets...` OR that the posted code does not match closely enough the true problem.

Comment: If the fgets() function is hanging when no input available, you could setup a select() statement, with a timeout, if no timeout, then char(s) available, read available characters, if enough chars read, process characters, otherwise go back to select() statement  if select timeout occurs, skip characters processing

Comment: Getting pretty hard to figure out what to answer now. Perhaps edit the question and clarify what is wanted?